# granting permission to android application that is set as device admin

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, airwatch

I am testing a mobile device management app and would like to grant permission using adb. I have seen several posts where the following is suggested:

> adb shell pm grant [package_name]
>   android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

or

> adb shell pm grant [package_name] android.permission.READ_PROFILE

Neither of these have worked for me. For 'READ_PROFILE' I got a return of 
"Operation not allowed:java.lang.SecurityException: Package #{App_Name} has not requested permission android.permission.READ_PROFILE"

While for 'WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS', no message got returned. I tried both on M and L.

Answer (score 1):

You can't grant permission if it is not requested in AndroidManifest.xml
First you need to add the permission in AndroidManifest.xml as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"
```

Then you can grant the permission from adb because due to security reasons you can't simply grant the permissions from adb without adding the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml